# I want to run an applescript whenever a certain person signs onto my Messages buddy list

Tags: applescript, ichat, messages

I want to run an applescript whenever a certain person signs onto my Messages buddy list

I am aware you can run applescripts for messages events, however I don't know how to check if it was that person who signs in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a `buddy became available` event, that passes in a `buddy` object. You can use one of the attributes on this object to see 'who' it is (`handle`, `name` or `full name`, for instance).

You can attach an arbitrary script to an event, in the way described at [bynkii.com](http://www.bynkii.com/archives/2010/03/ichat_scripting_trick_for_adam.html)